# react convert strings to react components

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-component

So this might be kinda weird, I have an array of strings and a bunch of React components as well.
For example:

```
const str = ['server','volume','route']

const Server = () => 'This is a server'
const Volume = () => 'This is a server'
```

and so forth, you get the idea.

I am trying to map the str to matching react Components and return the components.

I know I can use a loop and a switch to check for each item and return the respective component, but is there any creative idea like this:

```
{str.map(Y => <Y />)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very common use case, but definitely possible.
First turn all items into components

```
const data = const str = ['server','volume','route']
const components = data.map(x => props => <div {...props}>{x}</div>)
```

Now render each one

```
return components.map((Component, i) => <Component key={i} customProp='foo'/>)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an object as components map, something like this :

```
const componentsMap = {
  "server": Server,
  "route": Route,
  "volume": Volume
}

{str.map(key => {
  const TheComponent = componentsMap[key];
  return <TheComponent />
})}
```